# How to set the column in a Grid to autoshrink if there is space?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, layout, windows-phone-7.1

I have the following Listbox in my Windows Phone 7.5 app.  Basically the ItemTemplate for the listbox contains an image, some text, then an image.

If I set the Visibility property on one or both images to Collapsed, I'd like the text column to expand to its maximum size (rather than wrap text), e.g. take up the space that was previously taken up by images.  Conversely, when I set the Visility of the images back to Visible, I'd like the images to appear and the text to contract.

How can I pull off something like that in Xaml?

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="ProjectIcon" UriSource="Images/Dark/appbar.delete.rest.png" />
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="58"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="58"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource ProjectIcon}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="48" Height="48" />
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{StaticResource ProjectIcon}" Visibility="Visible" Width="48" Height="48" />
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the Width of both column 0 and 2 to Auto, and give them a MaxWidth of 58?